# Eigenstate of spherical harmonics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spherical-harmonics

> $$ \psi(\theta,\phi) = 1/(2\sqrt{3\pi}) [ \sqrt{5} \cos\theta + \sin (\theta + \phi) + \sin(\theta -\phi) $$
>
> Calculate $\hat{L}^2 \psi$ and $\hat{L}_z \psi$. Is $\psi$ an eigenstate of $\hat{L}^2$ and $\hat{L}_z$?

I solve and I get  $\hat{L}^2 \psi$ = 2$\hbar^2 \psi$ and  $\hat{L}_z \psi$ = $-\hbar [(\sqrt{2}/3) Y^1_1 + (\sqrt{2}/3) Y^{-1}_1]$

It is clear to see that $\hat{L}^2$ is an eigenvalue and thus an eigenstate. But for  $\hat{L}_z$, it is not an eigenvalue. Is it still an eigenstate?

Can someone explain this to me?
Thank you.

Comment: It is a coherent superposition of counter-propagating spherical harmonics.

Answer (score 1):

The given $\psi(\theta,\phi)$ is a sum of three spherical harmonics. Using the same notation as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#Spherical_harmonics), we have
$$
\psi(\theta,\phi) = \sqrt{5} Y_1^0 - \sqrt{2} Y_1^1 + \sqrt{2} Y_1^{-1}.
$$
These three spherical harmonics $Y_1^0,Y_1^1,Y_1^{-1}$ are degenerate, sharing the same degree $l=1$ but not the same order $m$. Thus $\psi(\theta,\phi)$ is an eigenstate of $\hat L^2$, but not of $\hat L_z$.

Comment: Does it mean with the same degree l, although order m is different, it will always be the eigenstate of the operator?

Comment: @Hames For $\hat{L}^2$, yes.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint:

You should try to write down $\psi(\theta,\phi)$ as a combination of spherical harmonics.

Comment: I did with my working. Just that it's too long to type here and I am only confused with the eigenstate only.

Comment: You should write it down in your answer. Anyway, if you wrote down $\psi(\theta,\phi)$ as linear combination of spherical harmonics, which are eigenstates of both $L^2$ and $L_z$, you've arrived to your answer, see if after applying $L_z$ on $\psi$ you can write it down as something like a constant times $\psi$ itself. If not, it's not an eigenstate of $L_z$.

Comment: I will write it down next time. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

> It is clear to see that $\hat{L}^2$ is an eigenvalue and thus an eigenstate.

This statement is not mathematically correct because $\hat{L}^2$ is an operator. An operator can't be an eigenvalue or an eigenstate. Instead, an operator can have eigenstates with corresponding eigenvalues.

By the definition of eigenvalues and eigenstates, it follows from $\hat{L}^2 \psi  = 2\hbar^2\psi$ that $\psi$ is an eigenstate of the operator $\hat{L}^2$ with eigenvalue $2\hbar^2$.

In the case of $\hat{L}_z$, you can't deduce whether or not $\psi$ is an eigenstate from the equation you reached. Try expressing $\psi$ as a linear combination of spherical harmonics and see if you can then write $\hat{L}_z \psi$ as $\psi$ multiplied by a constant. If that turns out to be possible, i.e. $\hat{L}_z \psi$ can be written in terms of $\psi$ alone, then, by definition, $\psi$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{L}_z$ with eigenvalue given by the constant mentioned before.

Comment: Understood, thank you!